# SharePoint - Change Themes Style Sheet

Tags: css, sharepoint, themes

I'm using the Belltown theme in a sharepoint portal and there are some styles that I want to change change in the Belltown stylesheet.  I thought that I could just edit the theme.css file located at:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\THEMES\BELLTOWN

and restart the web server, but the style sheet isn't changing for me.  What file should I be editing to change the stylesheet of a theme, or are there other steps that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you re-apply the Belltown theme to your site it will pick up your changes. When you apply a theme Sharepoint copies the contents of the TEMPLATE\THEMES\ *THEME FOLDER* to the site.

The other option would have been to point Sharepoint Designer at the site and modify the styles there which would apply them direct.

Comment: It I reapplied the theme, but it still doesn't seem to be updating the change.  I'll have to mess with SharePoint designer instead.

Comment: Actually, I changed the theme and then changed it back and it looks like it worked, thanks.

Comment: If you point Sharepoint Designer at the site and make the changes there it does not save it to the Site Theme. Thus when you apply the Theme to anoter site the changes will not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a new style sheet can be an iterative process.  For this reason, it may be helpful to use the [CSS Import Trick](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/brandsppart2.aspx) described on Heather Solomon's blog.

This could be helpful in that you won't have to re-apply the theme every time you make a change to the style sheet.  just change the file on the file system and refresh the browser page.